# Javascript function not defined using Moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm fairly new to javascript and recently started by foray into casual web development. I have a function that is supposed to return the number of days since the date entered. The code is contained below.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
function daysSince(date) {
    var i = moment(moment().format('YYYYMMDD')).diff(moment(moment().format(date)));
    return i;
}
</script>
```

For an unknown reason this function is not defined, and I would like help figuring out why. I've compared it to other working functions on my page and can't tell what I'm doing wrong. I've verified that the main line of code (the defining of i) runs properly when input into the console. Any help in determining the problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it perhaps moment that is undefined, rather than your function? Where are you calling it from?

Comment: should call moment function after its reference

Comment: How and where do you call `daysSince()`, and what is the specific error that you see in the console when running that code?

Comment: nnnnnn and dpix: I'm calling the function directly, on it's own line. As in: daysSince(20170106);. I have yet to write the rest of the program, I want to get this working first. The specific error is "ReferenceError: daysSince is not defined"

Andy Chen: What do you mean by calling a moment function after its reference?

Comment: Where on the page is the script that calls ```daysSince```? It will need to be in a script tag loaded *after* that script tag that defines the function

Comment: I had the function defined below everything else on the page. In hindsight my mistake is rather silly, but all the same I'm glad it was solved. Thank you all very much for your support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following worked for me:

```html
<html>
<body>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    function daysSince(date) {
      return moment().diff(date, 'days');
    }
    console.log(daysSince(new Date('3/1/2016')));
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Maybe it's just an issue of ordering your scripts.

Comment: Thank you, it was an issue with the ordering of my scripts. I am also modifying my code to be more like yours as it is far more efficient.

Comment: Guys. If you don't mind, could you tell me what's the proper way to order the scripts? I'm having the same issue here as well.

Comment: @Ye'ThuraAg scripts should be in reverse dependent order - The "main" script here depends on moment (it assumes `moment` is defined) so the moment script is loaded first.